# groovy spock mocking spring autowired beans

Tags: spring, unit-testing, groovy, autowired, spock

I have bean:

```
@Service
public class EQueueBookingService {

    @Autowired
    public EQueueBookingClient eQueueBookingClient;
```

And I try to write some test for this bean EQueueBookingService using Spock.
https://code.google.com/p/spock/wiki/SpockBasics

My mock is

```
class EQueueBookingServiceTest extends Specification {

@Autowired
EQueueBookingService testedService;

EQueueBookingClient eQueueBookingClient = Mock(EQueueBookingClient);

def setup() {
    testedService.eQueueBookingClient = eQueueBookingClient;
}
```

and test method:

```
...
setup:
CancelBookingResponse response = new CancelBookingResponse();
...
eQueueBookingClient.cancelBooking(_, _) >> response;
when:

def result = testedService.cancelBooking(request);

then:
result != null && result.bookId == bookId
```

Why eQueueBookingClient doesn't mock?

When I debug it: in test - I see Mock instance, when I go to method - I see real bean instance.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found solution!

need implement setter for this client and use it in setup like:

```
private EQueueBookingClient eQueueBookingClient = Mock(EQueueBookingClient);

    def setup() {
            testedService.setBookingClient(eQueueBookingClient);
        }
```

If define client in service as public and use = it doesn't work;
For example:

```
testedService.eQueueBookingClient = eQueueBookingClient;//mocked instance doesn't work
```