# Stub Method in Spring Spock (Groovy) not being executed

Tags: spring, unit-testing, groovy

I have the following unit test I am working on.

```
@ContextConfiguration(
        loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader,
        classes = ManagementApplication.class
)

    @WebAppConfiguration

class CTest extends Specification {


    @Autowired
    ClRepository clRepository

    @Autowired
    CoService coService

    @Autowired
    ClService clService

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository

    @Autowired
    TopicRepository topicRepository

    @Autowired

BasicAuthService authService

TopicService topicService  =  Spy(TopicService){
    createTopicForCo(_) >> null
}

def setup(){

}

def "Simple Test Create"() {
    given:
    def cl = ClRepository.findOne(1L)
    def sess = new Co(active: true, title: "Testing", cl: cl)
    topicService.createTopicForCo(sess) >> null
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(coService, "topicService",topicService);

    when:
    println "Testing creation of coaching session"
    sess = coService.create(sess)

    then:
    def coachingSessions = coService.findAll()
    println coachingSessions
    coachingSessions.size() > 0
}
}
```

I see that a topicService Mock object is being created.
`ReflectionTestUtils.setField` changes the `topicService` within `coService` with the Mocked one.

However, when `createTopicForCo` is called from within the topicService reference contained coService, the original implementation is called instead of my `createTopicForCo(_) >> null`.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30303706/groovy-spock-mocking-spring-autowired-beans

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/using-spock-test-spring

Comment: basically, set the `topicService` in a `setup` method, don't use the reflection kludge

Comment: @tim_yates Quite annoying having to expose a private variable. Any other way to do it?

Comment: you shouldnt have to expose it, because groovy cares not for your private declaration.  just try setting it, and you should be able to leave it private

Comment: @tim_yates thanks it worked. I added the setter because it is a Spring project using groovy and the field is private. I was getting an error that the field is private :( Anyway to go around that?

Comment: was it an error, or a warning?  Make the setter package scoped, then so long as your test is in the same package, you can call the setter, but no-one outside the package can